# Calling Jenkins Job from a PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell, authentication, jenkins-pipeline, remote-access

I am writing a PowerShell script to call a Jenkins job remotely. I am running into a 401 or 403 no matter what I try and I have tried over 30 different variations of this script. I am unsure why I am getting a 401 or 403 so if you can let me know if I am doing something wrong, would be great!

PowerShell Script

```
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic credentials")

$user = 'user'
$pass = 'api-token'

Invoke-RestMethod 'http://jobUrl/job/jobName/buildWithParameters?DOBUILD=true&BUILD_MODE=Release&SELECT_BUILDS=ALL&BUILD_COMPONENTS=ALL' -Method 'POST' -Headers $headers

Start-Sleep -Seconds 45

$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($user, (ConvertTo-SecureString $pass -AsPlainText -Force))

$status = Invoke-RestMethod "http://jobUrl/job/jobName/lastBuild/api/json" -Method Get -Credential $credentials

$returnStatus = $status.result

Write-Output $returnStatus
```

Output for the above script

```
Invoke-RestMethod :
Error 401 Unauthorized
HTTP ERROR 401 Unauthorized
URI:/job/jobName/buildWithParameters
STATUS:401
MESSAGE:Unauthorized
SERVLET:Stapler
Powered by Jetty:// 10.0.16
At C:\temp\OneDrive - Teradyne\Jenkins\test3.ps1:7 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod 'http://jobURL/job/jobNam ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
At C:\temp\OneDrive - Teradyne\Jenkins\test3.ps1:13 char:11
+ $status = Invoke-RestMethod "jobURL/job/jobNa ...
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

I initially used postman to make a post call and I actually got my initial powershell script from there and it looks like the following:

```
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic credentials")

$response = Invoke-RestMethod 'http://URL/job/jobName/buildWithParameters?DOBUILD=true&BUILD_MODE=Release&SELECT_BUILDS=ALL&BUILD_COMPONENTS=ALL&UPLOAD_IMAGE=YES' -Method 'POST' -Headers $headers
```

This script from postman works but when I got to add in more to receive status from Jenkins, I received a 401 or 403. I have used api token authentication with job token and username/password and nothing seems to be working.

My jenkins is configured to receive request remotely.

Comment: Does your user that you generated the token from have the necessary access?

Comment: what kind of access do the user need? @MB

Comment: Permissions to receive status from Jenkins. If this user is an admin, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: User is admin but still doesnt work. I double checked the credentials and user has access. Any other thoughts that I could research so I can solve this problem? @MB